# FB Like and Send

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

I am working on FB like and send button,I am having an issue with these
I have made a page with some meta tag info because of which FB object debugger can validates a page
In this section i've set og:url to the URL of the page on which like button is places

and on the href property of like button i have given Request.URL,the problem is it is not liking/sending the URL which i mentioned og:url instead it is sending Facebook.com in message

Below is my meta information

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# tbsname: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/tbsname#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="242015609188249" />   
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://mywebsite.com/Course/Profile/1381765" />
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Details" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="" />
```

Below is my FB like button:

```
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="@Request.Url" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

and i am accessing http://mywebsite.com/Course/Profile/1381765 in browser

Comment: If you want our help, you should tell us the _real_ URL of the page you are having problems with; otherwise there’s little to be said about your problem, because it’s not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the like button should be

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mywebsite.com/Course/Profile/1381765" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: Brother code is same,i am making the like button in the similar way

Comment: Can you show me a link for where you have the like button implemented?